# jQuery: Identify particular element among for loop elements and manually trigger twitter bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to keep track of article bookmarks for a user. The one's that are already added and the one's that are newly added. A quick check is made through ajax call, to check if the bookmark already exist. I am adding the information to be shown through popover dynamically, either `Bookmark Exist` or `Bookmark Added`.

Here's the popover button :

```
<button class = "btn btn-primary" name = "bookmark" id = "bookmark_list" value = "{{post.slug}}" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right"> Add Bookmark </button>
```

The problem that I am facing here is that, once I add the `data-content` to the popover and click it, the popover of other for loop elements also shows up.

```
success: function(data){
    if (data.status){
        $("#bookmark_list").attr("data-content", "Already Bookmarked");
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').click()
    }
    else{
        $("#bookmark_list").attr("data-content", "Bookmark Added !");
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').click()
    }
```

This results in multiple popovers getting clicked. I tried identifying the exact instance by using the unique `value` attribute:

```
var popover_value = $(this).attr("value");
```

Having got the popover's `value`, I tried to get the element using `$('[value = popover_value]')` and adding `data-content` dynamically. But, the identification of the exact instance using value isn't happening.

```
$('[value = popover_value]').attr("data-content", "Already in list");
$('[value = popover_value]').click()
```

How do I do this so that only the current instance `Add Bookmark` button is clicked? Thanks !

Edit 1 :

Here's the Django template : https://pastebin.com/c8hwksad

Here's the javascript code : https://pastebin.com/7YWUTpGc

Comment: I am a little confused, are you always wanting to click the button with the id of `bookmark_list`?

Comment: please make a jsfiddle...

Comment: @JoeLissner : Yeah. In this case, I am listing out all the articles and each article has a add bookmark button. I am listing out all the articles available by using a for loop.

Comment: @DanielH : Okay..But will an image help?

Comment: I think having the full relevant html and javascript would help a lot. For instance, none of the code you have shown us is part of a loop.

Comment: Added the code under `Edit 1`..Do you need more ?